# Simpson's Rule using for loops (numerical integration)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numerical-methods, simpsons-rule

I am trying to code Simpson's Rule in python using for loops and I keep getting an assertion error and cant find out why.

```
def integrate_numeric(xmin, xmax, N):
    xsum = 0
    msum = 0
    h = (xmax-xmin)//N

    for i in range(0, N):
        xsum += f(xmin + i*h)
        print (xsum)

    for i in range(0,N-1):
        msum += f(xmin + (h/2) + i*h)    
        print (msum)

    I = (h/6) * (f(xmin) + 4*(msum) + 2*(xsum) + f(xmax))
    return I
```

f:

```
def f(x):
    return (x**2) * numpy.sin(x)
```

sample:

```
assert numpy.isclose(integrate_numeric(xmin=0, xmax=4, N=50), 1.096591)
```

Comment: can you include f, and a sample input that crashes?

Comment: @ChristianSloper yeah sure

Comment: Why are you only making 4 function evaluations?

Comment: @MarkDickinson what do you mean?

Comment: You have N = 1, range(0,N) is only 1 step

Comment: @OliverMoore: You only make four function calls `f(something)`, in your next to last line. For Simpson's rule with N+1 points (N divisions), you should be calling `f` N+1 times. You want to be summing `f` values in your loops. Instead you're summing the *arguments* to those calls (the `x` values).

Comment: @MarkDickinson do you mean in the for it should be:
xsum +=  f(xmin + i*h)

Comment: @OliverMoore: Yes, exactly.

Comment: @MarkDickinson when I change the code to that I still just get an output of 0

Comment: @OliverMoore: Yes; that's not the only issue with the code.  You want `(xmax-xmin)/N` instead of `(xmax-xmin)//N`. There may be other problems.

Comment: @MarkDickinson ok Thank you I am now not getting just 0 outputs but i am still getting the same assertion error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fixed version of your code:

```
import numpy

def integrate_numeric(xmin, xmax, N):
    '''                                                                                                                               
    Numerical integral of f from xmin to xmax using Simpson's rule with                                                               
        N panels.                                                                                                                     
    '''
    xsum = 0
    msum = 0
    h = (xmax-xmin)/N

    for i in range(1, N):
        xsum += f(xmin + i*h)
        print(xsum)

    for i in range(0, N):
        msum += f(xmin + (h/2) + i*h)
        print(msum)

    I = (h/6) * (f(xmin) + 4*msum + 2*xsum + f(xmax))
    return I


def f(x):
    '''Function equivalent to x^2 sin(x).'''
    return (x**2) * numpy.sin(x)


assert numpy.isclose(integrate_numeric(xmin=0, xmax=4, N=50), 1.096591)
```

Notes:

- The ranges in the two `for` loops have been changed: we want the first `for` loop to go from `xmin + h` to `xmin + (N-1)*h` in steps of `h` (so `N-1` total values), and the second for loop to go from `xmin + h/2` to `xmin + (N-1)*h + h/2` in steps of `h` (`N` total values).
- In the final computation, there's no need to apply `f` to `msum` and `xsum`: those values are already sums of `f` values. The only places we still need to evaluate `f` are at `xmin` and `xmax`. (Note: this was already fixed in an edit to the question.)
- The line `h = (xmax-xmin)//N` needs to be `h = (xmax-xmin)/N`. You just want a regular division here, not a floor division. This is likely the cause of the zeros you were getting originally: `h` would have been `0`.